# Jenkins How to check which jobs are consuming a file from Config File Provider?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

There are around 3 files inside `Config Files` ($JENKINS_URL/configfiles/) which are consumed by approximately 500 of 2000 jobs in my Jenkins instance. I am trying to find the 500 jobs which will be impacted if I make a change on a config file. Is there any way to categorize the files and jobs?

I tried using the `Configuration Slicer` plugin but that was not able to provide this information. Clicking on each job and navigating through the configuration is proving to be cumbersome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [Plugin Usage](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plugin-usage-plugin/) plugin? It does not scan pipeline, only freestyle. Or you can just grep the job config.xml for the plugin string "config-filenprovider" and your Jenkinfile for "configFileProvider". Or scan w/groovy.

Comment: I installed `Plugin Usage` and it does the job! Lucky for me everything is in freestyle. Can you respond as an answer and I can accept it, thanks @IanW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plugin Usage](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plugin-usage-plugin/) plugin is probably a more suitable tool than [Configuration Slicing.](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configurationslicing/)

It [does not fully scan pipeline](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67243), only freestyle.
**Update 2023-01-09:** As of [version 4.0](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plugin-usage-plugin/releases/), "Adds analyzer for pipelines (scripted and declarative) based on last runs".
It also [nicely reports](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/plugin-usage-plugin@master/screenshot.png) on job specific plugin vs global and system plugin usage.

Or you can just grep the job config.xml for the plugin string `plugin="config-file-provider` and your Jenkinsfile for `configFileProvider`. Or scan w/groovy.

If you are also using [Managed Scripts](https://plugins.jenkins.io/managed-scripts/) plugin, then also scan for `managed-scripts`